# What is the name of a hosting service that allows me to control an operating system on their server?

Tags: remote-access, hosting

What is it called when you remotely access an operating system on a server. So that you can control the server as if it was your own computer?

I thought it might be called VPN but they did not offer remote access.

I want to search the internet so I can sign up for one but I cant figure out what the correct term is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is VPS, or "Virtual Private Server".

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server):

> A virtual private server (VPS) is a virtual machine sold as a service
>   by an Internet hosting service.
>
> A VPS runs its own copy of an operating system, and customers have
>   superuser-level access to that operating system instance, so they can
>   install almost any software that runs on that OS. For many purposes
>   they are functionally equivalent to a dedicated physical server, and
>   being software defined are able to be much more easily created and
>   configured.

A VPN is a "[Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)", which is something different. :)

There are many server hosting companies out there for you to choose from, with many different types of servers and pricing, a little web-searching should get you plenty to investigate. :)

Comment: Thanks i was looking all night for VPN and didn't realise :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to rent a "dedicated server", or at least a virtual private server (VPS). You will be given root/administrator access to the server and will have full control over it. There are MANY different companies that offer this, ranging from about $10/month for virtual to 100 times that price for high end servers.

Comment: Thanks, i found them :)
two perfect answers idk which to best

Answer (score 2):

it's called a [vps](http://e-commerce101.org/hosting-your-e-commerce-site/) (virtual private server). with vps, you basically just rent a remote computer which you can access through RDP (Windows OS) or SSH (Linux). you don't have to host a website with it (dont need to install a web server).